# Spliting / extracting from raw data column to multiple columns based on a criteria table MySql

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables

1st one address table

```
Country State       city        ZIP code
India   Andhra      Vizag       535001
India   Andhra      Vijayawada  520001
India   Andhra      Tirupathi   530001
India   Karnataka   Bengalore   400120
India   Tamilnadu   Chennai     400001
USA     Newyork     Newyork     666601
USA     Newjersy    Newjersy    666501
```

and 2nd is customer table

```
Customer    Raw_address                          City   state   Country ZIP code
X01         D No:123VizagAndhraIndia                    
X02         #46,XYZ streetBengaloreKarnataka                    
X03         #123 Dash Street Newjersy
```

now need to update customer table as

```
Customer    Raw_address                         City        state       Country ZIP code
X01         D No:123VizagAndhraIndia            Vizag       Andhra      India   535001
X02         #46,XYZ streetBengaloreKarnataka    Bengalore   Karnataka   India   400120
X03         #123 Dash Street Newjersy           Newjersy    Newjersy    USA     666501
```

I have given SQL Code for table creation and values

```
CREATE TABLE `Address` (
    `country` VARCHAR(50),
    `State` VARCHAR(50),
    `City` VARCHAR(50),
    `Zip code` VARCHAR(6)
);

insert into Address(country, state,city,`zip code`)
values
('India','Andhra','Vizag',535001),
('India','Andhra','Vijayawada',520001),
('India','Andhra','Tirupathi',530001),
('India','Karnataka','Bengalore',400120),
('India','Tamilnadu','Chennai',400001),
('USA','Newyork','Newyork',666601),
('USA','Newjersy','Newjersy',666501);

CREATE TABLE `Customer` (
    `Customer` VARCHAR(8),
    `Raw_Address` VARCHAR(500),
    `City` VARCHAR(50),
    `State` VARCHAR(50),
    `Country` VARCHAR(50),
    `Zip code` VARCHAR(6)
);

insert into Customer (customer, raw_address)
values
('X01','D No:123VizagAndhraIndia'),
('X02','#46,XYZ streetBengaloreKarnataka'),
('X03','#123 Dash Street Newjersy');
```

I have tried join in many ways but no success.

Comment: Please complete your question.

Comment: You should provide your sql statement.

Comment: SQL statement added

Answer (score 0):

Finally i figured it out.

```
UPDATE customer c
JOIN address a ON c.Raw_Address LIKE CONCAT('%', a.city ,'%')
SET 
        c.city=a.City,
        c.state=a.State,
        c.Country=a.country, 
        c.`Zip code`=a.`Zip code`
```